# What dose the Webpack "output.chunkFormat" do exactly?

Tags: webpack, configuration, webpack-dev-server

Ive started using the tool Browserslist lately to separate my modern and legacy builds. When i tried to run `webpack serve` (webpack dev server) to serve the bundles, webpack gave a warning that i havn't ever seen prior to configuring Browserslist. It basically said that i had to set the `output.chunkFormat` option before it can serve the bundle, so i did and it works fine now. The option basically specifies the module format of the bundles.

I would like to understand why i need to set it or why webpack cares about the module format of the bundles, as well as what relation it has to Browserslist. Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, webpack needs to know the environment in advance where your bundled code will run. And Browserslist can provide it with that information.

For instance, if you're going to run your bundled code on browsers supporting ES Modules, webpack would consider outputting ES Modules.

Say you have browserslist installed without a configuration, webpack won't be able to decide what kind of code to output, hence you'll need to specify [`output.chunkFormat`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputchunkformat).

Generally, setting a [`output.target`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/) would be enough as webpack can derive the environment from it.

Comment: Im having a hard time understanding what it would mean for Webpack to "output" es modules. Wont they be ES modules regardless since i wrote the code using "import" and "export" statments? Also, webpack never asked for me to set the ```output.chunkFormat``` until i set browserslists configuration (via a ```.browserslistrc```). Idk, it seems pretty weird to me.

Comment: You can learn more in details https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933. Maybe you can share a reproducible repository, as I don't have such an issue with `.browserslistrc` enabled.

Comment: Overall I agree with @chenxsan that relatively compared with `.chunkFormat`, per-global-configuration of `.target` should be enough . So yeah @chenxsan , upvoted as well . Also, if anyone reading comment section, this discussion raised by me , may help to clarify some of nuances for this subject [link](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/issues/5917) . Thank you